# How do I create native looking popups in a web extension for Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want a native looking popup (menu) in a Firefox web extension. Example:

[image: example]

---

#### What I have now

*Irrelevant parts omitted*

manifest.json:

```
"browser_action": {
  "browser_style": true,  // injects chrome://browser/content/extension.css
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
}
```

popup.html:

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-list">
        <div class="panel-list-item">
            Item 1
        </div>
        <div class="panel-list-item">
            Item 2
        </div>
        <div class="panel-list-item-separator"></div>
        <div class="panel-list-item">
            Item 3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This sort of looks like a native menu, but it's not perfect: Menu item hover states have a border and I don't know what html and class names are required for creating a menu item with an icon.

#### Question

**How do I get the result of the example image above *without writing my own CSS?***

Comment: Check out the files here https://github.com/FirefoxUX/StyleGuide/tree/8e892076461f558060fe590e8a5e65b265e369d6/mocks/shorlander