# How do I get native UI colors inside web extension popups?

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I've been struggling to make my extension visually consistent with the foreground and background colors of firefox's (and chromium's) navigation bar; i.e. the area that contains the address bar, back and forward  buttons, menu button, ...etc.

So far I've tried to

1. use [system css colors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#System_Colors) `Window`/`WindowText` and `Menu`/`MenuText`, but neither give the correct colors.
2. add [`"browser_style": true`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Browser_styles) (`"chrome_style"` for chromium) to the relevant  "browser_action" key in the manifest file. The only thing that did was make text unselectable in firefox. No perceivable changes in color occurred.
3. set colors explicitly (e.g. `#333`). This works but is a tedious solution that requires extensive testing. It also fails for users who choose to change their browsers default theme.

**Question:** Is it at all possible to make the colors of an extension's popup visually consistent with the rest of the navigation bar in a platform agnostic manner?

Comment: There seems to be a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47485053/how-do-i-create-native-looking-popups-in-a-web-extension-for-firefox), but the scope of acceptable answers was limited to non-custom browser CSS solutions by the author. This question is broader and has no such limitation. Any web technology is acceptable as long as the solution is reliably consistent.

Comment: There is no solution for Chrome. You can provide an option for the user to set the colors manually.

Comment: The situation is a bit better now with the advent of media queries that allow you to choose colors based on whether the user's agent is in "dark"/"light" mode, but these are still insufficient